# corpus with selected files in a directory

Tags: r, tm, corpus

I want to read a single file as a single document in a corpus but didnt find any sloution,i have tried with

```
>fdat <- readLines(fname)
> reuters=suppressWarnings(Corpus(VectorSource(fdat),readerControl = list(language = "en")))
> reuters
A corpus with 139 text documents
```

Or Is it possible to choose some selected files form a directory within a corpus

```
#reading all the files within directory
Corpus(DirSource("C:/test"), readerControl=list(language="eng", reader=readPlain))
```

as in I want to read  "c:/test/abc.txt" and  "c:/test/xyz.txt" only from directory and each file as an document.any help,thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pattern` to match the file names:

```
DirSource(directory=path_directory,pattern="abc.txt|xyz.txt")
```